# Backbone.js Uncaught ReferenceError to Underscore Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a Backbone Application.

My json looks like this,

```
{
  "cities": [
    "Kävlinge",
    "Lund",
    "Enskede",
    "Vadstena"
  ]
}
```

My Backbone Collection Code

```
var Cities = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'configuration/city.json'
});

var Index = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.cities = new Cities();
  },
  el: '.page',
  render: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.cities.fetch({
      success: function(cities){
        console.log(cities.models[0].attributes.cities);
        var template = _.template($('#city-dropdown').html(),{cities: cities.models[0].attributes});
        self.$el.html(template());
      }
    });
  }
});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '' : 'home'
  }
});
var router = new Router();

var index = new Index();
router.on('route:home',function(){
  index.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

The console.log statement just before the underscore template function prints my required Json Array, But in my script tag, it just Uncaught ReferenceError: cities is not defined,

Is my Json incorrect, or is my Backbone code incorrect, I'm confused. Seems silly. Please assist.

```
  <script type="text/template" id="city-dropdown">
      <select class="selectpicker">
        <%=  _.each(cities, alert) %>
      </select>
    </script>
```

Comment: The behavior of `_.template` changed recently (see the duplicate), I suspect you're seeing that change in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of underscore 1.7.0:

> Underscore templates no longer accept an initial data object. `_.template` always returns a function now.

So now the second optional argument of the `_.template` function  is used for setting template options. Pass the object to the complied function:

```
var template = _.template($('#city-dropdown').html());
self.$el.html(template({
   cities: cities.models[0].attributes // cities.toJSON()
}));
```

Comment: But until 1.7.0 (which came out on 2014-08-26) you could say `_.template(template_source, data)` to go straight to HTML without the intermediate step. A lot of tutorials and older code haven't caught up yet.